# Why gcc lacks of optimizing heap allocation away in local contexts?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

Consider the following simplified example:

```
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

int test_lack()
{
    auto lam = []
    {
        return 10;
    };

    // move lam to the heap
    void* ptr = new decltype(lam)(std::move(lam));

    // retrieve the result of lam
    int res = (*static_cast<decltype(lam)*>(ptr))();

    if (ptr) // important
        delete static_cast<decltype(lam)*>(ptr);

    return res;
}
```

[GCC 5.2 -O3 compiles it into](https://goo.gl/89Zv2i):

```
test_lack():
  sub   rsp, 8
  mov   edi, 1
  call  operator new(unsigned long)
  mov   esi, 1
  mov   rdi, rax
  call  operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
  mov   eax, 10
  add   rsp, 8
  ret
```

[Clang 3.7 -O3 optimizes this into](https://goo.gl/KYdBME):

```
test_lack():
  mov   eax, 10
  ret
```

**Why is Clang capable of optimizing the given code whereas GCC fails?**

Are there any compiler flags or code improvements which could allow GCC to perform more aggressive optimization to the given code?

---

**Just a short addition to the answer:**

[GCC 5.2 doesn't implement](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html) standard proposal [N3364](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3664.html) which means it can't optimize the given call to operator new out like Clang does it.

Comment: after testing it appears only clang 3.7 does this.  clang 3.6 returns the same assembly as gcc5.2

Comment: @sabbi Good catch there, i allocated the lambda on the stack again and gcc optimizes it as expected: https://goo.gl/pmQ0T6 .

Comment: I think the null test before delete is unnecessary.

Comment: I took a view over my original code and it seems like GCC optimizes the code if std::malloc and std::free is used to allocate memory whithout doing the null check (which means if the code is correct it fails and it optimizes it if the code could cause sigsev's): https://goo.gl/o8v9g3